# Capacitor of infinite capacitance

Tags: capacitor

What is the significance of a capacitor with a capacitance which tends to infinity? If it is touched with a body having finite capacitance, what will be the charge on the body?

Comment: If it has infinite capacitance, then it can never have a voltage greater or less than zero. So, basically, it is a short circuit.

Comment: If it somehow has a voltage other than zero, then it will essentially be an ideal voltage source.

Comment: Well, an infinite capacitor is so theoretical that you can assume that whoever made it, can make it with whatever initial voltage necessary.

Comment: Consider it to be an ideal voltage source. I had a question as homework on these lines. If a capacitor of capacitance C is touched to a capacitor of capacitance 2C  and then touched to a capacitor having infinite capacitanc. This process is repeated n times. Find the charge on capacitor C after the procedure.

Comment: The math in itself is not too difficult, you could calculate what happens when the "infinite" capacitor has a capacity of 10C and draw a graph from ten cycles. Then try it with a capacity of 100C, see what happens to the numbers. You'll probably notice what's happening while you are making the calculations (best by hand!).

Comment: Well, consider it an ideal voltage source with the voltage set to zero. So when you connect a capacitor to it, it will drain that capacitor to zero Volts (just like shorting it out with a conductor).

Answer (score 1):

There is no significance other than as a learning tool. It's a pure virtual concept that can not exist in reality.

Treat it like you would \$\infty\$ in maths - it's not a number, but it's useful to have things *approach* infinity, to show that something applies in the general case.

Comment: can you please enlighten me how to solve the problem posted as a comment by me few minutes ago. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @SanikaKhadkikar Sorry, I'm not a teacher, I don't enjoy theoretical homework puzzles. :)

Answer (score 0):

It means it in it wired in series to a finite capacitance then its equivalent  reciprocal of the finite capacitance .
In the other case it means if its wired in parallel to a finite capacitance then its equivalent to infinite capacitance. 
This follows from the capacitance formulas.

In real life the significance is that if you use a large enough capacitor value then you can use this as an approximation to an infinite value capacitor.

Comment: can you please show the method, my answer isnt matching after solving .

Comment: If by the description of your question   "touched" means wired in series, then  use zero as approximation

Comment: But I thought when ttwo objects touch they will come down tio the same potential.

Comment: @interestedinthis I don't think I've _ever_ heard anyone think that touching two capacitors means that they are connected in series. Before now, that is.

Comment: @pipe What I wrote makes sense to me  if you read all the information on this page. I tried my best to help the OP.